# Is it possible to say Salawat in the first Tashahhud?

Tags: salat, salawat, tashahhud

When praying 3 rakats and 4 rakats, there are two tashahhuds. So, when I’m sitting down in my second rakat, can I say the salawat before standing up and continuing my final two rakats?

Answer (score 1):

According to the majority of scholars (the Hanafis, Malikis, and Hanbalis), saying the Salawat in the first tashahhud shouldn't be done.

The Hanafis say it requires Sajdah Sahu if you do it forgetfully. The Malikis would even say the Salah breaks if you do it intentionally.

The Shafiis, on the other hand, say that saying Salawat in the first tashahhud is Sunnah and recommended.

See [Mawsooah Al-Fiqhiyyah](https://al-maktaba.org/book/11430/17084).

Comment: What if you didn’t know  what should I do?